# How to speed up the scrolling speed of GridView when the photos are all in local

Tags: android, performance, gridview, scroll

I've developed an app which shows each user's photos in a grid view. All the photos are really small with size 60*60. And all the photos are either in memory or in sdcard. (I developed a two-level cache, the first level is memory, and the second level is sdcard).

My test account has 400 photos. When I scroll the grid view, I still can see the grid view is not quite smooth. However, I checked the iPhone's photo gallery, and I found the iPhone's photo gallery is really quite smooth, so I want to know why iPhone is so good, and what can I do to improve the scrolling speed of the grid view in my app.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

ya it is because your adapter's getview() calls everytime, you can try with caching your image. [use Lazy List](http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip)